# Index out of bounds when using an copy of the variable

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't get my head wrapped around this, so I hope that you guys have an good explanation of why this code isn't working.

I've got an `ArrayList` of `Point` inside my `Warehouse` class.

This piece of code works right (it's inside an another class than the `Warehouse`):

```
Point lastPoint = new Point(0, 0);
ArrayList<Point> localPackages = this.warehouse.getPackages();

while(true){
    if(localPackages.size() > 0){
        lastPoint = this.determineClosest(lastPoint, localPackages);
        routeTemp.add(lastPoint);
        localPackages.remove(localPackages.indexOf(lastPoint));

    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

But the packages inside the `Warehouse` class get vanished away because the get removed. So I tried to make an copy of the variable and use that locally, but I've got no joy with that.

```
ArrayList<Point> localPackages = new ArrayList<>(this.warehouse.getPackages());
```

This is the error I recieve:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

I get that error at this line:

```
localPackages.remove(localPackages.indexOf(lastPoint));
```

Here's an print of the `localPackages` variable:

```
[
    java.awt.Point[x=1,y=1], 
    java.awt.Point[x=1,y=4], 
    java.awt.Point[x=2,y=0], 
    java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3], 
    java.awt.Point[x=0,y=1], 
    java.awt.Point[x=0,y=4], 
    java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0], 
    java.awt.Point[x=4,y=2]
]
```

So why do I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I copy the variable, but not when I use the original variable?

Comment: Well what would you expect to happen if `localPackages` doesn't contain `lastPoint`?

Comment: indexOf returns -1 if the element isn't found. Might want to print out lastPoint as a check...

Comment: @JonSkeet and nneonneo, Good point on that. But I forgot to copy that piece of code to. So that isn't the problem. The thing is that it's exactly the same code, but the copy variable doesn't work, while to "normal" one does.

Comment: "So that isn't the problem." Yes it is. You're calling `remove` with an index of -1, which is what you'll get if `indexOf` returns -1, which it will if the value isn't in the collection. Why don't you show us a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, but which you think should work? (It's not really clear what you mean by "copy the variable" by the way.)

Comment: Post more code please.  It's possible that `determineClosest` is using the original array and not the copy being passed in.

Comment: @pathfinderelite ow boy, That was indeed the problem. That's one way to feel myself dump... If you could make an answer of it, I could accept it. (or remove my question, that's up to you)

Comment: @JonSkeet with copy i meant that i copied the values of one and put it inside an new variable.
But pathfinderelite pointed me in the right direction. I was using an pointer to the `warehouse` variable.
So thank you for baring with me!

Comment: Please take this as a learning experience - next time, show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, so we don't need to guess what's happening.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's an learning experience indeed. And I'll try to remember that and use it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `determineClosest` is using the original array and not the copy being passed in.